# How can I get multiple values in a tag? ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I had a Component with select and option tags. However, I want to get each value from ( like in this code) when onChange. How can I get each values in that code? Thanks for your helps

```
const HandleChange = (e) => {
    // Which keyword can I use to get value2: data.tax?
}

const Cities = () => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <select value={city} key={city} onChange={HandleChange}>
          {dataFile.map(data => (
            <option value={{value1: data.code, value2: data.tax}} key={data.code}>{data.name}</option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
```

Comment: can you add a codesandbox of this code, so that it will be easy to understand

Comment: I glad to see your help. However, I don't know why I cannot access to that website. I added a comment in code question, so you may see it again. I hope to see your solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to use `value` here. Value attribute specifies the data that is submitted with the form but React apps don't follow normal HTML form submission patterns. I would recommend [Material UI](https://mui.com/) for form elements like this. Otherwise you can write your own custom wrapper component for option that takes in a value prop and update state on change. If you *really* want to use `value` attribute, then you could call `value={JSON.stringify({value1: city.code, value2: city.tax})}`. Server side you would deserialize the json.

Comment: and if I use ```value={JSON.stringify({value1: city.code, value2: city.tax})}``` Can I get each value from e.target.value? If can, which keyword should I use to seperate on that? Thank you.

Comment: You could access options values through `e.target.value.value1` and `e.target.value.value2`

Comment: I tried that but it wasn't working. I just got ```undefined``` value